# grep 'post_content' while parsing with cat & pipe into 'post_name'.html

Tags: unix, sed, grep, yaml, cat

**sample entry:**

```
  post_content: " some <strong >blablablabla</strong> text in <html>"
  post_title: Kontakt
  post_password:
  post_name: kontakt
```

**question:**
i have an yaml-file with entries like above and i like to parse the content of post_content with cat & grep and pipe it in to different file.

```
   $ cat posts.yaml | grep post_content >> different-file.yaml
```

This works. very well :)  but in this way i only excude all *post_content* from the *posts.yaml
on top of it i like to separate each *post_content* in to separate filea named like *post_name.yaml* - i think its possible to do with some sed-foo merge this in one line of shell comand. but atm i have no idea to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '/post_content:/{content=$0} /post_name:/{print content>$2".yaml"; close($2".yaml")}' posts.yaml
```

#### Example

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat posts.yaml 
post_content: " some <strong >blablablabla</strong> text in <html>"
post_title: Kontakt
post_password:
post_name: kontakt
post_content: " some other text in <html>"
post_title: Kontakt
post_password:
post_name: contact
```

We then run:

```
awk '/post_content:/{content=$0} /post_name:/{print content>$2".yaml"; close($2".yaml")}' posts.yaml
```

After this command is run, there will, in addition to `posts.yaml`, be two new files in the current directory:

```
$ ls
contact.yaml  kontakt.yaml  posts.yaml
```

The contents of the new files are:

```
$ cat kontakt.yaml 
post_content: " some <strong >blablablabla</strong> text in <html>"
$ cat contact.yaml 
post_content: " some other text in <html>"
```

#### How it works

- `/post_content:/{content=$0}`

  Every time that we reach a line that contains `post_content:`, we save the line in variable `content`.
- `/post_name:/{print content>$2".yaml"; close($2".yaml")}`

  Every time that we reach a line that contains `post_name:`, we print the variable `content to a file  whose name is given by the second field on the line followed by`.yaml`.

Comment: this works but makes the named *post_name*[space].yaml but it WORKS :) Thank you!

Comment: @TheRojam Glad it works for you.  Regarding the issue of the unwanted space, I can't reproduce that.    If you still have that problem, tell me more about exactly what you are doing and how it differs from the example that I ran.

Comment: which OS do use? macOS or Linux? I used this under Linux in zsh.

Comment: @TheRojam I use Linux with bash.

Comment: problem found :D zsh interprets this command this different than bash :D

Comment: @TheRojam Very good.  Since the awk code is entirely in single-quotes, I'm surprised that zsh messes with it.  But, I'm glad you solved it.